# libGDX with MoPub (integrating AdMob) using RoboVM project for iOS

Tags: ios, libgdx, admob, mopub, robovm

I am building a game using the latest (as of date) libGDX nightlies , RoboVM nightlies, and MoPub bindings that are available [here](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings). I used MoPub bindings to show AdMob ads, and I managed to show AdMob test ads on iPhone simulator; however, only test ads are shown on the simulator, and I have not specified any code to show test ads.

The question is: is this normal? is it always going to be test ads on simulator? will real ads show normally on devices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad,

It is normal to see test ads once you have integrated.  You should be able to see actual creatives from AdMob once the ad network is setup within your MoPub dashboard.  It would take some refreshes to get the ads cached but then it would be serving to your simulator.

Another way to test the type of creatives that are coming in is to select ‘Test Ad’ in the Inventory tab over at mopub.com.  In the Chrome browser, content may be blocked from being loaded.  A shield icon in the address bar will appear.  Click on the shield and then click on ‘Load unsafe script.’  Then click the ‘Run Again’ button.

You should be using your AdMob's 'Ad Unit ID' and not the 'Legacy Publisher ID.' I know it may be confusing as within MoPub's dashboard it mentions to have the 'Publisher ID' but really it should be the 'Ad Unit ID' from AdMob that should be entered.

Please consult this guide for more info: http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/1376821-how-to-set-up-updated-admob-revenue-reporting

Do you have marketplace feature enabled and seeing request/impression counts coming in?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have already linked AdMob and I can see AdMob test ads, not MoPub test ads, I have disabled marketplace, it is already telling me that it is still under review. Should marketplace be approved before I can see AdMob real ads?

Comment: I have also archived the MoPub Demo Order